# Wrong relative path when calling http.get()

Tags: javascript, relative-path

I can't get it since two hours, why this relative path is wrong. In an other angular-cli project I got exactlly the same structure of folders and the same relative path and it works. What's wrong here:

Here is my tree (calling from navigation.component.ts the json in folder dev_data):

[image]

Here is the way how I call it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadNavItems()
}

loadNavItems() {
    this.navItems = this.http.get("../../dev_data/navItems.json").map(response => response.json());
}
```

Got every time a 404: `GET http://localhost:4200/dev_data/navItems.json 404 (Not Found)`

I repeat myself, in an other angular-cli project the same structure (navigation comp in src/app and json src/dev_data) with the same relative path works! I have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: Is the server configured to serve files with an extension of .json?

Answer (score 0):

Your relative path would not work as you are expecting. First put the `dev_data` folder at same level as that of `index.html` and then supply the url as `./dev_data/navItems.json`

Another way is that if you don't want to change the location for the `index.html` then supply the relative url for the `.json` from the index.html

The main reason is that when you are executing the `http` request then the relative url is matched from the root i.e. where is the `index.html` file.